# How to Update a DataTypes.ENUM datatype in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, enums, sequelize.js

I have this sequelize model:

```
  var TableName = sequelize.define(
    "TableName",
    {
      id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
      name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      approvedTenure: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 0,
      },
      status: {
        type: DataTypes.ENUM,
        values: ["PENDING", "YES", "NO", "DON'T KNOW"],
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: "PENDING",
      },
      narrative: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, defaultValue: "" },
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
      tableName: "table_name",
      freezeTableName: true,
    }
  );
```

And when I run the following code trying to update the table:

```
const data = {id: 23, status: "YES", narrative: "I am good", approvedTenure: 2}

async updateTable(data) {
    return await TableName.update(
      {
        status: data.status,
        narrative: data.narrative,
        approvedTenure: data.approvedTenure,
      },
      {
        where: { id: data.id },
        returning: true,
      }
    );
  }
```

The table gets updated except the status column with DataTypes.ENUM as the data type. How do I go about updating the status column with the DataTypes.ENUM data type?